# start app with a single view then navigate to a tab view?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Can I start my app with a single view and navigate through views using `UIViewController` and add a tabbed interface (`UITabBarController`)?

Comment: can you provide any link or sample of a combination of single views, tabbed bar views and master-detail views together?

Answer (score 0):

If your project works with a StoryBoard in Xcodes Interface Buidler, than simply design your UIView as a new Scene, then select this scene and in the menu click **Editor / Embed in / Navigation Controller** or use **Editor / Embed in / Tab Bar Controller**.

Then wire this new Tab Bar Controller or Navigation Controller with a button's action from your "Initial Startin Scene".

The cool thing is: If you have a Navigation Controller you can once more do "Embed into Tab Bar Controller. Or if you have a Tab Bar Controller, then you can once more do "Embed into Navigation Controller".

Afterwards it may look like this:
[image: Single View triggers TabBar / NavBar]

Hope this helps.
If yes: dont forget to mark question solved.